# twitter bootstrap tooltip: using delay causes adjacent tooltips to stay visible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, delay

[ I found posts about how to setup tooltip delays, but nothing about the problem introduced if two links are adjacent ]

I added some delay to my tooltips to eliminate flashing as the mouse is moved quickly across links:

```
$('body').tooltip({
  selector: 'a[rel="tooltip"], [data-toggle="tooltip"]', 
  delay: { show: 100, hide: 100 } 
});
```

But that introduced persistent tooltip display when moving from one tooltip link directly to another (both are displayed).

You can see the problem at http://classygroundcovers.com/site/page?view=sitemap by hovering over "Finding your perfect plants" and moving the mouse down a line to "Plants & packages on sale".

If I remove the delay they work fine.

Any ideas how to retain the delay and make them behave properly?

Ref: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Thank you for your kind attention to this question.

Comment: I moved the example demonstration of the problem to http://calmness.com/tmp/tooltip/1.html ad I am going to have to remove the delay from the live site until this is fixed. I tried to create a fiddle but was not able to figure out how to do that, it has what I think is the relevant info, not sure what I am missing to demonstrate the problem there - http://jsfiddle.net/kazaleski/EaqDN/2/

Answer (score 1):

Omitting the "hide" delay made the problem go away.
This let me keep the "show" delay that was needed to prevent the flickering.

This does not solve the bug, but is a viable workaround.